# Is it safe to use urlencode to store messages in a database?

Tags: php, oracle, web, emoji, urlencode

I'm buidling a client for whatsapp, and the only way I found to be able to store the messages without getting the emojis converted to `¿` (Oracle DB), was to use urlencode to store the message, and then using urldecode when retrieving from the base. I've run a lot of tests and didn't have any problem, but I'm very concerned if it is or not a good practice and if can cause problems in the future.

Comment: It [works well](https://dbfiddle.uk/3nBBj_yw) without any encoding/decoding. What is your database character set? Alternatively you may use `nvarchar`

Comment: Safe? Probably. Wise? No. You have a mismatch between how your data is encoded, and how your database is configured to store and/or retrieve it. You can kludge around it by applying a arbitrary encoding on top, but you're not solving the underlying issue and making your app a bit more complex than it need be.

Comment: Run [these queries](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#nls) to find the DB and client character set.  Also see the Globalization chapter in [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/php/201212-ug-php-oracle-1884760.pdf).  You should not be url encoding anything - if your DB has an appropriate character set.

Comment: @ChristopherJones Change the character set of the database is not an option, unfortunately. :(

Comment: What is the character set of the DB? (Update the question with this info)